# Stress Test Planning - JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Stress Testing and would like to ensure that I am approaching it in a right way.

Out team's objective is to determine whether our application's current back-end infrastructure (AWS API Gateway, AWS Lambda, and AWS MySQL RDS) can support 100,000 daily users. The way I am thinking about this questions is as following:

**Input:**

- 100K users/day
- 16 active hours / day - since we have global user base
- User spends on average 30 min with the app

**Planning:**

1. Most likely users will not be uniformly distributed over 16 hours, therefore let's use 3 times average which is (100K users / 16 hours) * 3 = **18,750** users / hour
2. Although, we are expecting users to spend 30min on our app, let's assume that only 10min of that time will end up in the peak zone. Therefore we need to simulate **3,125** concurrent users (18,750users/hour * 10min / 60min)

**Questions:**

1. Is the above logic sound?
2. What would be the right way to simulate such load in JMeter?
3. Should we look into number of threads (if yes how many)?
4. Should we look into the throughput (if yes what value should we be looking for)?
5. Else?

Any advise will be highly appreciated.

Thank you,
gen

Answer (score 2):

What you describe looks like a [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing#Software_load_testing), [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing#Software) is something different, it's not about checking whether the application can support 100k users but more about finding the first [bottleneck](https://qa-platforms.com/detecting-bottlenecks-performance-testing/)

Normally the process looks as follows:

1. You start with 1 thread (virtual user)
2. You gradually increase the load until:

   - You reach the maximum number of users your application is supposed to support
   - You detect performance degradation (increasing response time, decreasing throughput, errors start occurring, whatever comes the first)

On ideal system when you increase the load by a given factor the throughput (number of requests per second) should increase by exactly the same factor and the response time should remain the same (or go down).

If response time goes up it means that the system is not capable of handling the load and you need to identify the cause (slowest component) and check if you can optimize it somehow.

For the "load testing" your assumptions look valid

More information: [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough)

Comment: Thank you DmitriT. What metric would you use to define "You reach the maximum number of users your application is supposed to support". Is it requests per minute or the number of concurrent threads?

Comment: It is according to your application NFR/SLA

Comment: Thank you. So in my example I need to simulate 3125 CC VUsers over 10min. Since we do not have resources to create 3125 parallel threads, we will have to use 15,625 requests/minute (3125 users * 50 req in peak time / 10 min). So if the app can sustain such load, will it mean it can handle 100K users/day in my example?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is fine except that you seemed to be confusing VUsers with *visits x hour* (or **target** throughput a.k.a. **capacity**). The following [calculator](https://www.webperformance.com/library/tutorials/CalculateNumberOfLoadtestUsers/) validates your calculations.

IMO, since you know the targeted TP (SLA), a simple way to implement the workload is to submit it (requests) using the [Arrivals Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ArrivalsThreadGroup/). This TG will instantiate the number of threads needed to sustain the targeted TP.

Comment: Thank you CarlosG. Does it mean that I should no be thinking in terms of concurrent VUsers but instead focusing on simulating the desired requests per minute using the plugin you suggested?

Comment: Correct. Your goal should be to determine what is the "capacity" (throughput) of your application environment (together with respective "response time" (a.k.a. "speed")) for a certain level of load (VUsers). Keep in mind that this a "non-linear" relationship. The following [link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/500812251/) towards middle of the page you'll find a graph that shows this relationship.

Comment: Thank you CarlosG. The article is very informative.